# Как получить имя метки при клике по ней?

Tags: javascript, 1с

Встраиваю яндекс-карту в 1С. На ЯК вывел пронумерованные точки(примерно так выглядит всё это:

[image: Изображение]

Теперь нужно при клике по метке получить её номер, либо координаты, чтоб потом съориентироваться, что это за адрес в 1С.

Сейчас дошел до того, что при клике на метке у меня определяются координаты клика(но не метки).

```
function getmyPlacemarkPosition(coordPosition) { 
    document.getElementById('CoordX').value = coordPosition[0].toPrecision(15); 
    document.getElementById('CoordY').value = coordPosition[1].toPrecision(15);
}
```

**Вопросы у меня следующие:** как мне получить объект метки при клике, как обратиться к её заголовку?

Прошу сильно не пинать, ибо профан в JS и ответить по подробнее.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Код выложите. И непонятно, что все-таки нужно: получить объект метки или заголовок?

Comment: Не удалось выложить код сразу, а теперь символов не хватает. Буду кусками

Comment: http://snap.ashampoo.com/fmOUUfvIKKersixRgHnRuGaOyHsQd2mIH275ATgl0k6RSUEY6RlRYLbsTTDWpPAW

Comment: function getmyPlacemarkPosition(coordPosition){

    document.getElementById('CoordX').value =      coordPosition[0].toPrecision(15);
    document.getElementById('CoordY').value = coordPosition[1].toPrecision(15);}

Comment: Достаточно будет заголовок получить.